# How to pass the id along with the names in datalist used in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I want to pass the id (`wpIn.id`) in `ng-model` and to show the text (`wpIn.presentationName`) in the UI. But, despite providing the id in the value field, the id is being shown in the UI.

```
<input type="text" class="taskSearch" placeholder="Enter Name"
  ng-model="wpInItems" list="wpItemsIn" />
<datalist id="wpItemsIn">
  <option ng-repeat="wpIn in workProductsList | orderBy :'presentationName'"
    value="{{wpIn.id}}">{{wpIn.presentationName}}</option>
</datalist>
```

Comment: Can you add JS part as well? It would great to create a runnable snippet of your code

Comment: `<input type="text" class="taskSearch" placeholder="Enter Name" ng-model="wpInItems" list="wpItemsIn" />
            <datalist id="wpItemsIn">
              <option ng-repeat="wpIn in workProductsList | orderBy :'presentationName'" value="{{wpIn.presentationName}}">
            </datalist>
            <text class="add_class" ng-click="DisplayWpInput()">&nbsp;ADD</text>`
I want to pass {{wpIn.id}} in DisplayWpInput() function instead of  {{wpIn.presentationName}}. DisplayWpInput function is defined in controller.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem with your template code.

```
  <select ng-model="selected">
    <option ng-repeat="wpIn in workProductsList" value="{{wpIn.id}}">{{wpIn.presentationName}}</option>
  </select>
  <span>Selected value is {{selected}}</span>
```

Data :

```
  $scope.workProductsList = [
    {
      id: 1,
      presentationName: 'First one'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      presentationName: 'Second'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      presentationName: 'Last'
    }];
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/bWXaLMWWm8dt5eEi9RzH?p=preview

Comment: Template code is okay but, as I provide the id in value field, it is coming in dropdown in UI instead of the presentation name. I want the id in model instead in UI. In UI, I want to show presentation name.

Comment: If you close look, selected model is the ID, not the presentation name. And showed text is presentation name

Comment: Yeah, but the id is getting shown instead of presentation name in UI dropdown. That is the problem I am getting.
I need to pass the id in controller and show the presentation name in UI, which I am not able to do so.

Comment: Did you check the example I provided to you? Isn't what you expect? https://plnkr.co/edit/bWXaLMWWm8dt5eEi9RzH?p=preview

Comment: I have used datalist for autocomplete, not select box. Please check my code once, which I have provided above.